# IP authentication for library

Tags: authentication, ip, authorization

I have very abstract description of the project. Ok, publisher wants to give access to several books to some library. He gives access by IP range (common method in publishing business, as I understand). So, users who will go to the library and use library's computers and browse book catalog can download these books.

Now question. This system should work if user login to the library from **home** computer (actually system like this already exists and I don't understand how it can work). And problems begin. User login to the library, but he will have his own IP address obviously. What can I do to give this users access to the books if I know only IP address range of the library.

I see 2 methods:

- use "HTTP referer" field from the request. Which is very insecure
- use third-party authorization meсhanism. I don't know exactly how I can do it, so I will appreciate any help

It looks like I'm trying to do pretty the same thing as this user -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999304/using-ip-to-identify-institution-school-university-library-etc

Anyway I found several references of IP Range authorization for libraries and universities. So, somehow it works. Can you explain how does it work for people who use their **home** computer?

Comment: `This system should work if user login to the library from home computer... but he will have his own IP address obviously` Yes and no. If the user is logged in on a library machine from his home computer, and requests that the library machine he's logged into should do the download on his behalf, then the user gets the benefit of having the remote machine's IP address be the one used for the transaction. The remote machine is an [Internet proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) in this case.

Comment: The same principle holds true if the user logs into a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN) at the library, except in that case the user can route his traffic through the public IP address of the library transparently (by sending packets through the network interface created by the VPN software. Usually, network interfaces map to actual physical NICs, with the exception of loopback. This is another exception to that rule).

Comment: @ParthianShot Thanks for answer. I think I should read about VPN. I don't understand very well how I can dynamically add user machine to VPN after he logged in to library site.

Comment: Well, that may not be how it's being done. They might also be using a federated authentication mechanism like [shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/). If all users need to do to get the service is login via a browser, then they're not using a VPN. When you said 'login' I wasn't clear whether you meant "in a browser" or "in another third-party tool".

Comment: @ParthianShot Ok, thanks. I found mentions about shibboleth, but I don't understand very well it's role. I will read about it. Maybe you know some good tutorials?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. Although I have found the official site pretty helpful, and shibby is used a lot in academic settings, so you shouldn't have too much trouble finding additional resources. And if you really want to find out exactly how the library is doing what they're doing, you could try sending an e-mail to the webmaster@ address. Worst case, they're annoyed and don't respond. Best case, they're flattered and feel compelled to explain.